# How to Filter/Remove record if 2nd field has different values in it in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

How to Filter/Remove record if 2nd field has different values in it...
Eg:

**ID   ,   NAME**

```
100 , ABC
100 , DEF
100 , XYZ
102 , ABC
102 , ABC
103 , ABC
```

**Output:**

```
102 , ABC
103 , ABC
```

Note: 100 should be deleted as it contains two different NAMES, and 102 should be taken only once in output..

Comment: ID and NAME are two fields in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Steps:

```
A = load 'file' using PigStorage(',') as (ID:int,NAME:chararray);
B = DISTINCT A;
C = filter B by NAME =='ABC'; 
D = filter B by NAME !='ABC'; 
E = join C by ID left outer, D by ID;
F = filter E by (D::NAME is null); 
G = foreach F generate C::ID as ID,C::NAME as NAME;
```

Hope this will help..